# (intellij) format xml with tag-end part on new line

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm using Android Studio, and layout xml indentation is auto-formatting in somewhat wrong way for me.

Instead of

```
<!-- case1: miss-diffs on git -->
<SomeXML
    attr1="hello" >
</SomeXML>
```

or

```
<!-- case2: wrong end(?) indentation level -->
<SomeXML
    attr1="world"
    >
</SomeXML>
```

I'd like to format my xml as

```
<SomeXML
    attr1="hello"
>
</SomeXML>
```

so that my git diff won't show any miss-diffs from case1,
and without wrong indentation level (case2) to confuse myself.

Are there any options in intellij for this?
Thanks in advance : )

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @VivekMishra it's about configuring intellij for xml formatting

Comment: @user2899136 when you type as 'case 3' (your preference) and try 'reformat code', will it change into case-2 or case-1?? Does't it preserve your original xml code style??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne nope it just changes to type2. (also, intellij forces indentation on the last line)

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I can manually delete indentation using shift+left to select indentation and doing backspace, but auto-formatting would just un-do what I was trying to do

Comment: @user2899136 try my answer and update. :))

Answer (score 1):

Go to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML**

Change the Scheme there to **Default**. Normally it doesn't restrict on what you are trying to do, unnless there is any defined settings.

[image]

Comment: nope this still falls onto case 2 when I'm manually trying to type the correct example, and auto-formatting changes to case1.

Answer (score 1):

On Android Studio 4.0.1:

Go to **Settings (or Preferences on MaxOS) -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> "Other" Tab**.

Check **Keep line breaks**.